# What is the Lazy<T> constructor called when Ninject inject Lazy<T> objects?

Tags: c#, ninject, lazy-loading

[Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642318(v=vs.110).aspx) have several constructors through which you can control the threading behavior of a Lazy instance. What is the constructor used by Ninject to create the injected Lazy instance? How I can specify which constructor Ninject must use ? if that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Story

Default is `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`
Change it by using one of the following:

```
 // for all Lazy's
 Bind<LazyThreadSafetyMode>().ToConstant(LazyThreadSafetyModeNone);

 // for a specific Lazy<FooBar>
 Bind<LazyThreadSafetyMode>().ToConstant(LazyThreadSafetyModeNone)
     .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(Lazy<FooBar));
```

Or alternatively you can use a Binding of `Bind(typeof(Lazy<>))` or `Bind<Lazy<FooBar>>()` in combination with

- [`ToMethod()`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context#factory-methods)
- [`ToConstructor()`](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/)

### Long Story

`Lazy<T>` support is implicitly provided by [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory).

By default ninject will resolve request for types which can be directly constructed (non-interface, non-abstract) by instanciating that type. That also goes for `Lazy`. It will then search for the constructor with the most arguments which it can supply and use that one (see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns#constructor-injection) and [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Selection/Heuristics/StandardConstructorScorer.cs))
Ninject.Extensions.Factory provides bindings for the `Func`s (see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/FuncModule.cs)]. But it does not provide a Binding for `LazyThreadSafetyMode`. Ninject will thus choose the constructor `Lazy(Func<T>)`. This constructor uses `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication` (see Remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329(v=vs.110).aspx)).